# Django multiple similar models

Tags: python, django

I want refactor some of my code in models because it's a little mess. I have couple models.

```
class Part(models.Model):
class Category(models.Model):
class Labor(models.Model):
```

And so on, seven in total. I am generating for them ID. For Part it is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not Part.objects.count():
        latest = 'XXX00000'
    else:
        latest = Part.objects.all().order_by('-par_id')[0].par_id
    self.par_id = "PAR" + str(int(latest[3:]) + 1).zfill(5)
    super(Part, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And it's pretty similar for rest of classes. Only name of class is changing, three letters identification and paramtere in *order_by*. I was wondering how can I do it DRY. Because it's 7 lines of code on each class that should be somehow shortened.

I was wondering maybe create BaseModel class inherited from it and somehow change only mentioned things. I would like to get some directions how can I do it better.

Edit:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    par_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=9, blank=False)
    par_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Part.objects.count():
            latest = 'XXX00000'
        else:
            latest = Part.objects.all().order_by('-par_id')[0].par_id
        self.par_id = "PAR" + str(int(latest[3:]) + 1).zfill(5)
        super(Part, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Category(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=9)
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Category.objects.count():
            latest = 'XXX00000'
        else:
            latest = Category.objects.all().order_by('-cat_id')[0].cat_id
        self.cat_id = "CAT" + str(int(latest[3:]) + 1).zfill(5)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That are two o my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `class BaseModel(models.Model):` and copypaste your `save` method there, but replace `Part` with `self.__class__` , for example

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    # some fields here

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        first_declared_field = self.__class__._meta.fields[1].name

        if self.__class__.objects.count():
            latest = getattr(self.__class__.objects.order_by('-' + first_declared_field)[0], first_declared_field)
        else:
            latest = 'XXX00000'


        field_value = first_declared_field.name.split('_')[0].upper() + str(int(latest[3:]) + 1).zfill(5)
        setattr(self, first_declared_field, field_value) 

        super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class SomeChildModel(BaseModel):
    pass
```

Comment: I added to my original post some more information. And your approach fit to this but there is small thing. For each class I can change kwargs with my data for example in order_by because it's string. How change par_id field to another?

Comment: you can get fields list in order they were declared in model `self.__class__._meta.fields`, but `self.__class__._meta.fields[0]` is id, so you need `...[1]`

Comment: "PAR" or "CAT" you can get using smth like this `self.__class__._meta.fields[1].name.split('_')[0].upper()`

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting is definitely a good idea.

You're not giving much information about the models. So there are 2 main options for inheriting models:

A) To use an AbstractModel which would hold the common fields and some common methods. And then use child models to extend the fields and methods as you need. Here is an example from the django docs:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(CommonInfo):
    home_group = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

B) If you're only interested in inheriting or extending the behavioural parts of your models (like the different methods for generating the id's), a proxy model would be a better option. Take a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Here is an example taken from the django docs:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```